# Distribution of variables

Tags: statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution, expectation

1.Let $X$ be distributed uniformly (0,1)

We have to find E(Y) and median(Y), given   $ Y=-2ln(X)$

I've reached the point of finding cdf of Y (sorry, I suck in mathx, even more than in statistics) $F(Y)$ = integral from x=(e^(y/2)) to $1$ ($F(X)$)
I'm stuck now.

2.Simular question is $X$ distributed normally with parameters  $(0, var)$ . The only difference I wasn't able to do anything.
We are supposed to find $E(Y)$ if $Y= |X|$

Thank you in advance, I really need your help.

Comment: Somewhere in your notes they might explain that computing the PDF of $g(X)$ is not necessary to compute its expectation since $$E(g(X))=\int_\mathbb R g(x)f_X(x)dx$$ Use this, twice.

Comment: Can you please clarify your formula for the CDF of Y?

Comment: The median should be trivial for a monotone transformation. If $U \sim \mathsf{Unif}(0,1),$ then $Y = 2\ln U \sim \mathsf{Exp}(mean=2).$ In the second part, $Y$ has a folded or half normal distribution. You may want to look at the related Wikipedia pages.

Comment: @BruceET thank u, already  did a several times.